# Outline the bottom of an textarea with textfield not equal on Mac/Firefox?

Tags: html, css, textarea

I am trying to align the bottom of an textarea to the bottom of a textfield. I just set the height of a the textarea with CSS

```
#your-comments {
    height: 87px;
}
```

Now on a PC + Chrome/Firefox it seems correct.

Even on my Mac + Chrome/Safari it seems to be correct.

The only problem is my Mac + Firefox, there is a gap of `5px`.

[image]

Is there a way the bottom of the textfield and textare align correctly?

Answer (score -1):

You can use tables to make it fit to work with different browsers.

eg: https://jsfiddle.net/praveen_solanki/dj5hmt0z/

```
 <table style="width:400px">
<tr>
  <td style="width:50%" ><input type='text' value='Name' />  </td>
  <td style="width:50%" >Comment Box   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td style="width:50%" ><input type='text' value='Age' />  </td>
  <td style="width:50%" ROWSPAN=3  ><textarea style="width:95%;height:100%;" type='text' value='comment' > </textarea> </td>
</tr>   
<tr>
  <td style="width:50%" ><input type='text' value='emailid' />  </td>
  <td style="width:50%" >  </td>
</tr>
```

in above code i have created table in which i have added a textarea and marked it height to 100% to match the fixed size.

Let me know if you have questions.